# Use Azure Active Directory to register custom users (programmatically)

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-acs

How can I use my Azure Active Directory to register (programmatically) users from an asp.net application?
Users must be able to register themselves with any email address (gmail,outlook,hotmail,etc..).
Each registered user has to be added in my azure active directory so as to be able to log himself in the future with the credentials with which he recorded himself.
There is a way to do it?

Comment: Hi @pinturikkio, to use Azure AD you need to have a custom domain. You either have to roll out your own user management or use social media integration. Check the documentation here: http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-2-building-web-applications-azure-ad/

Comment: Hi @Chris I have many custom domains, this link does not help me to do what I asked

Comment: These kinds of users would be considered "external" users in the directory. The Azure Management portal provides a UI for you to add users with an existing Microsoft Account to your directory. It's not the programmatic approach you are looking for but it will get you there. If it were supported, the Azure AD Graph API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130117.aspx) would be the way to go.  Unfortunately, adding external users is not supported by the API-at least not since I last tried this which was just a few weeks ago.

Comment: even that doesn't cover the requirement, as "external users" in AAD can only be a Microsoft Account (LiveID), which excludes GMail !

Comment: What about adding a new user on your AAD and using their email address as a username. May not work if the '@' symbol in their email address is disallowed by the 'Create User' Graph API. I'd be interested to hear how you go.